# Node - how can i pipe to a new READABLE stream?

Tags: node.js, websocket, stream, pipe, duplex

My app is supposed to take Web Audio streamed from the client, encode it as MP3, before sending it back out to clients via WebSocket.

I can currently encode and pipe to a file like this:

```
inbound_stream.pipe(encoder).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('audio.mp3'));
```

And if I *already* have a file on the server I can do this:

```
var mp3File = fs.createReadStream('audio.mp3');
          
            mp3File.on('data', function(buffer){
                io.sockets.emit('audio', { buffer: buffer });
            });
```

However, I want to access the encoded chunks in real time, and send those out to clients - *not* write to a file.

What I want is this, effectively:

```
inbound_stream.pipe(encoder).pipe(newReadStream);

        newReadStream.on('data', function(buffer){
            io.sockets.emit('audio', { buffer: buffer });
        });
```

I've looked at Duplex and Transform streams, but frankly I am still learning and the Prototyping made my head spin.

How do I do this? Thanks.

## UPDATE

The solution below from @Nazar Sakharenko certainly does what I wanted, but the overhead of live encoding seems to make this inpossible, so writing the encoded MP3, and pre-buffering it seems to be the only way (thanks to various people for the suggestion.)

However I still have problems with this approach. New question here:

[node.js - create a new ReadStream for a new file, when that file reaches a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727384/node-js-create-a-new-readstream-for-a-new-file-when-that-file-reaches-a-certa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation [readable.pipe(destination[, options])](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) the destination should be **stream.Writable**.

What you can do is to implement your own Writable stream:

```
const Writable = require('stream').Writable;

var buffer = [];
//in bytes
const CHUNK_SIZE = 102400; //100kb

const myWritable = new Writable({
  write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    buffer += chunk;
    if(buffer.length >= CHUNK_SIZE) {
       io.sockets.emit('audio', { buffer: buffer});
       buffer = [];
    }

    callback();
  }
});

myWritable.on('finish', () => {
   //emit final part if there is data to emit
   if(buffer.length) {
       io.sockets.emit('audio', { buffer: buffer});
   }
});


inbound_stream.pipe(encoder).pipe(myWritable);
```

thats all.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I really appreciate it.

It worked but unfortunately the encoding jammed up the stream, meaning it can't be used in real time. I wonder if I am better to write the file, and then stream that once it reaches a certain size, using growing-file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mp3 streaming, probably you can precache some decoded part of mp3 in memory and start streaming after minimal size was decoded.

Comment: Thanks @Nazar Sakharenko, I think the pre-cache idea is the only way, but I'm not sure how to correctly stat the file to begin sending chunks after a certain filesize. General workflow is on the client I use the getUserMedia API to stream PCM data from my soundcard to the node JS server, using socket-io-stream. The server encodes it as above to MP3 to save bandwidth and sends it in chunks back to the client, where it's decoded by AudioContext. Ideally I would use PCM data end to end, but I can't get AudioContext to play raw PCM data.

Comment: Just as an addendum to that @Nazar, I can watch the encoded file and use fs.stat to check for a certain size, but the problem is the event keeps firing and interrupts the stream.

Comment: I've created a follow up question that does what you suggested - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727384/node-js-create-a-new-readstream-for-a-new-file-when-that-file-reaches-a-certa

Comment: Can you compare buffers when you streaming from file, and from decoder? Something may be corrupted, in buffe, and compare chunk sizes.

Comment: Good idea but I went with your other suggestion, pre buffering. And having a recording of the stream is a nice bonus. I just need to know how to keep the stream running once the pre buffer is met.

Comment: I've answered in your other question, same example with saving to file